# Android MVP and framework specific code

Tags: android, bluetooth, mvp

I was reading an article by Dario Miličić regarding MVP [here](https://medium.com/@dmilicic/a-detailed-guide-on-developing-android-apps-using-the-clean-architecture-pattern-d38d71e94029#.8sgjc4z10). I also thoroughly went through the code he provided on [git hub](https://github.com/dmilicic/android-clean-sample-app). Anyways, i am pretty new to MVP for android and MVP in general, and so I have a question about what he said - "The implementation layer is where everything framework specific happens”. What if i have an android application that deals with Bluetooth? i.e. i have a small application to get a list of bluetooth devices using BluetoothAdapter which is an android class. So I started writing a use cases which was something like this

```
public interface BluetoothScanInteracotor {
    interface View {
        void onScanStarted();
        void onScanCompleted();
    }
    void scanForDevices();
}
```

but then realised that I cant do that because of its framework specific.

How would I go about this?
Forgive me if that's a silly question, but I might be confused about something and I need someone to help me understand.

Answer (score 3):

The CLEAN approach would be to implement a `BluetoothDeviceRepository`, which could have multiple implementations, one of which would actually access the system resources, but could easily be swapped for one with no external dependencies for test, etc. The Bluetooth device scan results would be converted by repository implementations to return POJO models that represented the information you needed, so that there would be no leakage of the Android system classes into this layer.

Comment: yea i thought of creating a new model for that but i then i thought that, that is recreating something which i would like to avoid too

Comment: And that is what you will end up doing a lot of with the CLEAN approach. :) It really does make unit testing so much easier, though, despite what sometimes feels like a lot of additional typing.

Comment: yea i guess, kind of makes me take have some control over thigns

Answer (score 1):

The issue with most MVP implementation out there is that they designate Activities and Fragments as Views, and propose to use "Android framework independent" presenters.

This sounds good until one encounters issues like yours - Bluetooth framework is part of Android framework, so it is not clear how to use it in the presenter that shouldn't depend on Android specific classes.

After researching MVx architectures on Android for several years I realized that the only sane conclusion that can be derived is that Activities and Fragments are not views, but presenters.

The more detailed discussion of this subject can be found here: [Why Activities in Android are not UI Elements](http://www.techyourchance.com/activities-android/).

Based on this idea I proposed an alternative implementation of MVP in Android: [MVP and MVC Architectures in Android](http://www.techyourchance.com/mvp-mvc-android-1/).

Comment: ah yes  I i think i read your comment suggesting this on one of the posts regarding MVP. Hmm well I guess it depends on what kind of application i am building too then. Looking at his code on github, everything seems to beworking great, and hand in hand.

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko, yeah, that's exactly what I thought too. I myself tried a bunch of approaches, including this "clean architecture" (BTW, it is rooted in ideas of Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin). The problem is that they weren't designed for Android, which is terrible in Separation of Concerns and Single Responsibility Principle. So these approaches look good on paper, but break apart in reality of non-trivial apps. Just think about runtime permissions - you can't really test that this logic works without testing the integration code in Activities... Anyhow, check it yourself - maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Hey vasily, dont wan't to make this comments feed a thread of its own haha but, i have to ask, after line 64 how does line 79 get notified [link](http://www.techyourchance.com/mvp-mvc-android-3/)? I tried searching in your github project, but i hit a wall, it lead me to the post method of your threading class.

Comment: i found it! its in the manager. im surprised the git repo search didn't work the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea in MVP model that not bad to share with you,
Everything that depends on the OS,should be treated as View, and Logic is Presenter,
For example Activity is a View, we use it to intract with UI ,for example get Text of a Textview, and when  we need to process on the text, we make a presenter class for this activity and also an interface to this presenter, then implement the interface in presenter,and call methods of interface in Activity with needed params(for example that Text)

If I want implement it in another OS, i should only change my Activity and get Text in other way,and remain process is same and doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

As you have come to know basics of Clean Architechure. The following example depicts how actual your MVP pattern is implemented.

Example:

```
interface BaseContract {
        interface BaseView {
            //Methods for View
            void onDoSomething();
        }

        interface BasePresenter {
            void doSomething();

        }
    }

    class BaseMainPresenter implements BaseContract.BasePresenter {
        BaseContract.BaseView view;

        BaseMainPresenter(BaseContract.BaseView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            if (view != null)
                view.onDoSomething();
        }
    }

    class DemoClass implements BaseContract.BaseView {

        //Create object of Presenter 

        /****
         * Example :
         * BaseMainPresenter baseMainPresenter = new BaseMainPresenter(this);
         */
        @Override
        public void onDoSomething() {
            //Deal with Context here.
        }
    }
```